What's the most modern NVIDIA Geforce graphics card I can get right now not needing a power connector?
What's the most modern NVIDIA Geforce graphics card I can get right now not needing an extra power connector?
Right now I have a Geforce GT 640, which is obviously very outdated and the graphics driver support is really bad.
Basically the whole PC is still fine for most things, but I would like to be able to test some cuDNN stuff to learn about it.
The means, that I need at least CUDA 11.0.
Also I would like to try some things with the Vulkan API.
So it has to be at least the Maxwell architecture, but for sure I would prefer something better.
The best I found myself is https://www.idealo.de/preisvergleich/OffersOfProduct/203842754_-geforce-rtx-3050-eagle-oc-6g-gigabyte.html.
Is there a better option?

Yes, there is technically a better option. The ASUS 3050 6GB OC Edition has a slightly higher boost clock of 1537 MHz.
There is also the RTX A2000, which can be considered better than the 3050 6GB by some metrics. However, it isn't a consumer-grade GPU and has different drivers and features, so it may not be the best choice for gaming.

The GeForce GTX 1630 or any "low profile" card. But these are made more to fit a spec and not built for power like the larger cards are.
Also, depending on your budget, you can get some high end cards, but these are pricey.
